# Creating new UIViewController instance, delete old one?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a webview I want to create a new instance of in certain situations.

I do it like this:

```
if(self.webViewController){
    self.webViewController = nil;
    [self.webViewController release];
}

self.webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TheWebView" bundle:nil];
```

in `self.webViewController` I listen to a `NSNotification`

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {
    // Custom initialization

  }
NSLog(@"INITING WebView");
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doPageRequest:) name:@"doPageRequest" object:nil];
return self;
}
```

However if I send a message `doPageRequest`, it gets invoked multiple times. So my assumption is that there are still more webView Instances "active", means: When I created the new instance, the old one is not freed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` in the `dealloc` method

Add the following, and remove the removeObserver line from your init method.

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The `self` changes as you recreate a viewcontroller, it's a pointer to a new part of the memory where your new ViewController resides.
So calling `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` inside the init will never remove a previous one you added in init.

Also, you set the `self.webViewController = nil;` before you call release on it, obviously that won't work (you're calling release on nil), so switch the order.

```
[self.webViewController release];
self.webViewController = nil;
```

Comment: hmm it makes sense what you say, sadly it doesnt work. I just found out the dealloc: of my UIWebViewController is never beeing called. Do you know how I can make sure it´s deallocated?

Comment: it only gets called once now. I have a different problem now, but that  be a new topic. Thank you very much!